# Why does Allah need to be good

Tags: islamic-philosophy

Why does Allah (swt) need to be good or moral in terms of human standards?

Does the notion of God need to be a moral and just being? Why cannot God almighty be unjust?

Finally, should we take God's justice and mercy for granted?

Comment: Your whole post needs some evidences to support your claims, who pretended all of this?

Comment: @Sassir, what do you mean pretended? This is a philosophical question and evidences can be found in the 99 names of Allah (swt) - الودود (Al-Wadud), اللطيف (al-Latif) and الكريم (al-Karim). The question is self is not bound to evidence but rather thought. Allah is absolute and absolutely independent, and so why does Allah (swt) need to be kind, generous or forgiving? Why cannot Allah be 'evil'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allah is Al-Ghani, which is to say He doesn‘t “need” anything whatsoever. He is not good because He needs to be good; He is Good simply because that is what He is. That is His nature. The Book says that He is forgiving because He inscribed the rule of mercy for Himself, (surat-ul-an‘am 6:54). On  the Day of Judgment we are going to be needy of His Goodness, Mercy, and Forgiveness. That transcends mere philosophizing. Alhamdulillahi Rabbil-Aalameen!

Answer (score 0):

It just doesn't work. E.g 1+1=2. Thats justice, single entity added to another single entiy makes 2. Thats law. if you say 1+2=2. Well that says 1 single entity added to two single entities, equals to two single entities. There's no balance. That's unjust. One entiy is non existent, yet we are saying it is there. The way everything works will collapse, theres no point of existence. 
Taking this info in the context of islam, e.g forgiveness(2),is caused by regrettable actions(1+1), if forgiveness was for everybody, even those that killed kittens(1+2) for fun instance, would the concept of forgiveness work? no. there's no point. As they say, everything happens for a reason, it's all code. Kind of like a matrix if you will, injustice will mean theirs a flaw, and the whole code will stop working.